# Windows Containers with docker reports HNS failed with error : The file cannot be opened because it is in the process of being deleted

Tags: windows, docker

I just unstaill docker, removed hyper-v and containers from windows 10 and reinstalled docker and allowed it to enable hyper-v and containers again. All with the same result when switching to windows containers that it cannot run a windows container.

```
C:\Users\pks>docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver cmd
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint big_babbage on network nat: HNS failed with error : The file cannot be opened because it is in the process of being deleted..
```

Have anyone seen semilar issues ? how do i figure out whats wrong?

Update:
I can create a new network and use it in each command and it works, but i am guessing it should work with default also.

```
docker network create -d nat --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.1 MyNatNetwork
docker run -it --network=MyNatNetwork <image> <cmd>
```